# Strange ambiguous overload involving a custom class

Tags: c++

My compiler tells me that there is an ambiguous overload. I cannot get my head around why it thinks this.

I have the following library in `example.h` (please scroll all the way down):

```
#ifndef EXAMPLE_H
#define EXAMPLE_H

#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

template <class T> class Matrix
{

  private:

    std::vector<T>      _data;
    std::vector<size_t> _shape;

  public:

    Matrix               (const Matrix<T> &) = default;
    Matrix<T>& operator= (const Matrix<T> &) = default;
    Matrix<T>            (                 ) {};

    Matrix<T>( std::vector<size_t> shape )
    {
      size_t n = 1;

      for ( size_t i=0 ; i<shape.size() ; i++ ) {
        _shape.push_back(shape[i]);
        n *= shape[i];
      }

      while ( _data.size()<n )
        _data.push_back((T)0);
    };

};

std::tuple<Matrix<double>,int> S2 (\
  Matrix<int> & in1, Matrix<int> &in2, std::vector<size_t> &shape \
)
{
  Matrix<double> out(shape);
  return std::make_tuple(out,10);
};

std::tuple<Matrix<double>,Matrix<int>> S2 (\
  Matrix<int> & in1, Matrix<int> & in2, std::vector<size_t> & shape,\
  bool a=false, bool b=false\
)
{
  Matrix<double> out (shape);
  Matrix<int>    out2(shape);
  return std::make_tuple(out,out2);
};

#endif
```

Which is called from the following file:

```
#include "example.h"

int main ( void )
{

  std::vector<size_t> shape;
  shape.push_back(11);
  shape.push_back(11);

  int n;
  Matrix<int>    in1({100,100});
  Matrix<int>    in2({100,100});
  Matrix<double> out;

  std::tie(out,n) = S2 ( in1, in2 , shape );

  return  0;
}
```

Which is compiled with `clang++ -std=c++14 example.cpp`

Comment: With the trailing \ s you have #defines that you haven't shown us.  Please provide a [MCVE].  Also showing the call with the problem would be useful.

Comment: I had purposefully excluded as many details as I could. Now have included some more. Hope this helps?

Comment: Does your second `S2` have default arguments?

Comment: Put together a short but complete example.

Comment: @aschepler Sometimes the solution can be so simple... It is just strange that I have been using this library using `pybind11` for a long time. And so far my compiler has never complained, and Python always has found the correct function.

Comment: Well, it's quite obvious now that you've shown the default args....

Comment: Indeed, a bit embarrassing. Again, I was really off-put by the fact that `pybind11` finds the correct overload, even with the defaults.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default values for the bool parameters makes the functions ambiguous,
as both functions can be called with the parameters (Matrix&, Matrix&, std::vector&).